# In Typesense, When i search 'brd' it doesn't show any results. Why it doesn't show results like bird, bard, etc.,?

Tags: search-engine, fuzzy-search, typesense

In typesense, Why fuzzy search is not woking for small word (len 4)?

```
const searchParameter = {
   'q': "brd",
   'query_by': 'title',
}
```

output:

```
{
    "facet_counts": [],
    "found": 0,
    "hits": [],
    "out_of": 9979,
    "page": 1,
    "request_params": {
        "collection_name": "books",
        "per_page": 10,
        "q": "brd"
    },
    "search_cutoff": false,
    "search_time_ms": 0
}
```

I want typesense show results, when i search 'brd'

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the default values for the parameter: `min_len_1typo` which is set to `4`.

This is set to 4 as default to reduce noise in the results.

But if you change that parameter to say `2` or `3` for example, you should see `brd` be auto-corrected.

This is documented here: https://typesense.org/docs/0.25.2/api/search.html#typo-tolerance-parameters